# C# drag and drop picturebox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I have 7 pictureboxes and I want to drag and drop each one of them. I have made the drag and drop but it takes with it the original picturebox which I drag it doesn't leave it on its place. This is my code:

```
        this.pbAND.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
        pbAND.MouseMove += pictureBox_MouseMove;
        pbAND.MouseUp += pictureBox_MouseUp;


        this.pbOR.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
        pbOR.MouseMove += pictureBox_MouseMove;
        pbOR.MouseUp += pictureBox_MouseUp;

    private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p = (PictureBox)sender;
            downPoint = e.Location;
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)p.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            p.Parent = this;
            p.BringToFront();
            DestroyIcon(icon);
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p.Left += e.X - downPoint.X;
            p.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y;

        }

    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = (PictureBox)sender;
        Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(p.Left - 1, p.Top));
        if (c == null) c = this;
        Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(p.Parent.PointToScreen(p.Location));
        p.Parent = c;
        p.Location = newLoc;
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do with drag and drop. Your code changes the position of the respective picture boxes so it's no surprise that they don't stay in place.

Comment: By saying drag and drop, do you mean changing their location in the form?

Answer (score 0):

> but it takes with it the original picturebox which I drag it doesn't
>   leave it on its place.

So you want to make a **copy** when the PictureBox is dropped?

In the MouseDown() handler, store the original location in the Tag() property:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        p = (PictureBox)sender;
        p.Tag = p.Location; // <-- store the Location in the Tag() property

        // ... rest of the existing code ...

    }
}
```

In the MouseUp() handler, put a **New PictureBox** in the current location and reset the original:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    p = (PictureBox)sender;

    // create a new PictureBox that looks like the original:
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
    PB.Size = p.Size;
    PB.Image = p.Image;
    PB.SizeMode = p.SizeMode;
    PB.BorderStyle = p.BorderStyle;
    // etc...make it look the same

    // ...and place it:
    Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(p.Left - 1, p.Top));
    if (c == null) c = this;
    Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(p.Parent.PointToScreen(p.Location));
    PB.Parent = c;
    PB.Location = newLoc;
    p.Parent.Controls.Add(PB); // <-- add new PB to the form!

    // put the original back where it started:
    p.Location = (Point)p.Tag;
}
```

Comment: i want to drag a picturebox but not the original picturebox but like a copy of it and i want to make an exact copy of the picturebox when i use my mouse_down event. Now when i drag drop i use moue down and it take the original picturebox not an copy so i can have a set of fixed pictureboxes where i can choce to make copies of them by drag droping . Kind ragrds and many thanks for trying to helo :)

Comment: Did you try the above?...it should be pretty close.  It will let you drag the original, but then when dropped it makes a copy and puts the original back.  Making a copy and dragging that while leaving the original is a little trickier.

Comment: yes but it does not make that when i drag it it doent make a copy of the picturebox i choce to drag instead the selected picturebox is returned to the initial postion.

Comment: Oops!...I forgot to add the new picturebox to form.  See update.

Comment: I saw it and when i try now it shows me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for p.Location = (Point)p.Tag; line.

Comment: That means you didn't place the location into the Tag() property.  Look back at my instructions where I said "In the MouseDown() handler, store the original location in the Tag() property".  You need to add the line of code below that to the MouseDown() handler.  I've edited it above to make it clearer.